# What is the English word for "accepted/acceptance by the society"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, vocabulary

What is the exact English word for "accepted/acceptance by the society"? I think the word I have heard before starts with "C".

Comment: Perhaps a *conformist*, or some form of *conform*? A better (longer) example using the intended word would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe you can give us a little context? It may help...

Answer (score -1):

**Convention**

A way in which something is usually done, especially within a particular area or activity.

> The woman who overturned so many conventions of children's literature...

Particularly used with Saussure in the context that words only have particular meanings because of convention.

Comment: What is *used with Saussure*?